# Spawning Python process with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, web, spawn

My goal is to run python code that the user would write on the website. I found out that `spawn()` could do it.

```
var process = spawn('python',["./script.py"] );
```

However, I do not want user to store their code in a file but rather i want their code to be executed directly. I want to take their code as a string and do something like this.

```
var process = spawn('python',pythonCodeString );
```

This method would obviously not work because `spawn()` takes file path as an argument. Are there other methods of executing user's python code with js?

P.S. I am making a website where one can edit an image using python code. For ex. user uploads an image and would want to change it to gray scale(all these transformation users can do with python)

Answer (score 0):

You could just automatically create the .py file from the inputted python code/string and then subsequently call it with spawn() and delete it once it has been executed, much like a "temporary" script, so that the user doesn't need to store it manually inside a file.

Comment: but isnt the server gonna be flooded with these files?

Comment: If you carefully delete them after execution, it won't. Still, I would advise against allowing clients to directly execute scripts like this, since it could lead to potential arbitrary code execution threats.